# Posting data to Web Api 2 controller via HttpClient Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got an WebApi controller in my application

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("contracts/{exchangeGuid}/exchangeInfos")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateContractExchangeInfo(Guid exchangeGuid,ExchangeDestination destination, ExchangeStatus exchangeStatus, string response)
    {
       //some login here
    }
```

I need to make a call to this WebApi method using HttpClient.
I've tried to make a PostAsync with form data but got an error that no such action was found on controller

Here is an example of my request

```
                using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = _baseAddress;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                    //Creating form content
                    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("destination", ((int)destination).ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("exchangeStatus", ((int)exchangeStatus).ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response", ipResponse)
                        });

                    //Sending POST 
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("api/contracts/{0}/exchangeInfos", contractGuid), formContent);

                    //Some more logic here
                 }
```

Is there any way to create post request and pass this parameters without changing WebApi action?

Comment: Do you need authentication? what is the HTTP verb you get from the error, 404 or 401? I would fire up [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) and try the plain way... then, when everything was working I would click *Code* button and copy the C# example and test it ... then just modify the code.

Comment: Yep. I need windows authentication. It's 404 error that returns in response

Comment: I've turned off Windows Auth and triend to send request via postman still getting 404

Comment: and you're sending as POST I would assume ... if that project was not mine or I could not run it locally, I would create a simple WebApi project with that only route and investigate why couldn't I reach it.

Comment: have you tested that Url for the web api yet? are you sure its correct?

Comment: Url seems to be valid. But still getting 404 when I try to post action parameters via form data.  So I've desided  to make one complex object to contain all this properites and send it via PostAsJsonAsync and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

If the action can not be found I would try to access the endpoint first before building the client, if you launch the web api project in debug mode as localhost, try to type the URL in the browser and see if you can hit the endpoint using the same parameters you specified.